# QWidget::mousePressEvent() not called

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qgraphicsview, mousepress

I'm working on a TreeViewNode class derived from QObject and QGraphicsItem, responsible for creating the individual nodes of the tree view (which displays a family tree) and adding them to the scene. I made sure to include the `setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);` method in the class constructor and I overloaded mousePressEvent like so:

```
void TreeViewNode::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        qDebug() << "Mouse pressed on node: " << m_node->getPatient()->get_Name().c_str();
        emit clicked(this);
    }
    QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

The clicked signal is defined in the header file as `void clicked(TreeViewNode* node);`
Then I have a `updateSelectedPatient` slot in MainWindow

```
void MainWindow::updateSelectedPatient(TreeViewNode* node) {
    selected->setSelectedPatient(node->getNode()->getPatient());
}
```

and the corresponding connect statement in the MainWindow constructor

```
connect(treeView, &TreeViewNode::clicked, this, &MainWindow::updateSelectedPatient);
```

When I execute I see the nodes that have been added to the scene in the view but when I click on them nothing happens (I know through debugging and also because the setSelectedPatient() method updates a widget that shows the patient information of the currently selected patient); it seems like mousePressEvent() is not being called at all.. any help would be really appreciated, thank you for your time!

edit:

```
//TreeViewNode.hpp
class TreeViewNode : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem)

private:
    node* m_node;
    Family_tree* m_family;
    QGraphicsScene* m_scene;
    static std::set<node*> addedNodes;

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event) override;

public:
    TreeViewNode(node* node, Family_tree* family, QGraphicsScene* scene, QGraphicsItem* parent = nullptr);
    TreeViewNode* getTreeViewNode(node* n);
    node* getNode() const;
    static void clearAddedNodes();
    void updateNode(Patient& patient);
    QRectF boundingRect() const override;
    void drawBranches(QPainter* painter);
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override;

signals:
    void clicked(TreeViewNode* node);
};

//TreeViewNode.cpp
TreeViewNode::TreeViewNode(node* node, Family_tree* family, QGraphicsScene* scene, QGraphicsItem* parent) : QGraphicsItem(parent), m_node(node), m_family(family), m_scene(scene) {
    if (m_node == m_family->get_root()) {m_scene->addItem(this);}
    addedNodes.insert(m_node);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
    qDebug() << "Scene item count: " << m_scene->items().count();

    if (m_node->getFather()) {
        auto father = m_node->getFather();
        if (addedNodes.count(father) > 0) {return;}
        TreeViewNode* fatherNode = new TreeViewNode(m_node->getFather(), family, m_scene, this);
        fatherNode->setPos(-50, -100);
    }

    if (m_node->getMother()) {
        auto mother = m_node->getMother();
        if (addedNodes.count(mother) > 0) {return;}
        TreeViewNode* motherNode = new TreeViewNode(m_node->getMother(), family, m_scene, this);
        motherNode->setPos(50, -100);
    }

    if (m_node->getSpouse()) {
        auto spouse = m_node->getSpouse();
        if (addedNodes.count(spouse) > 0) {return;}
        TreeViewNode* spouseNode = new TreeViewNode(m_node->getSpouse(), family, m_scene, this);
        spouseNode->setPos(100, 0);
    }

    int childCount = 0;
    for (auto child : m_node->getChildren()) {
        if (addedNodes.count(child) > 0) {return;}
        TreeViewNode* childNode = new TreeViewNode(child, family, m_scene, this);
        childCount++;
        double xPos, yPos;
        xPos = pos().x() + 50 + 100 * (childCount - (m_node->getChildren().size() + 1) / 2.0);
        yPos = pos().y() + 100;
        childNode->setPos(xPos, yPos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a normal event filter and check if is it a mouse press, release or move event then cast it to a mouse event and then just do whatever you want with it.

**Example:**

```
bool YourWidgetClass::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event)
{
if (object == YourInstance)
{
   switch (event->type()) 
   {
    case QEvent::GraphicsSceneMousePress: 
    {
       QMouseEvent * mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
       switch (mouseEvent->button())
       {
          case Qt::LeftButton:
                // Handle left button pressed here
                return true;

            case Qt::RightButton:
                // Handle right button pressed here
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }
        break;
     }
   }
}
```

Don't forget to install the event filter on your class

```
YourClassCtor->installEventFilter(this)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Comment: It's difficult to answer without understanding how the user created the class

Comment: @Franco it is, so that is why you should get the question clarified before answering an unclear question. Right?

Comment: @JamesRisner how to do that?

Comment: In your case, it looks like the OP clarified between when your answer was posted to now. So I removed my downvote because the OP updated their question. But do one of these for future unclear questions: 1) Comment on the question asking for clarity 2) Flag the question as Needs Improvement -> Needs details or clarity so they will be closed until clarified.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I'm currently trying to install the event filter on each TreeViewNode through the constructor but it doesn't trigger the eventFilter method this way; the only way it works is that if I install it on the scene but even then it emits the signal only for the very first node added and none of the others which makes me believe there might be something wrong with the constructor.. basically the constructor tells me that the node has already been added to the scene as soon as I enter it, before reaching the m_scene->addItem(this); line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see from your question that you need it for anything special. the signal `&QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged` is not enough for you? Is the item set to interactive?
So simply put:

declare a slot:

```
public slots:
   void selectionChanged();
```

define the slot:

```
void MainWindow::selectionChanged()
{
  qDebug() << ...... ;
}
```

and connect:

```
connect(scene,&QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged,this,&MainWindow::selectionChanged);
```

Comment: you're right, I think that would suffice but the issue is that even though I put setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable); in the constructor (or in the paint method) the nodes in the view are not actually made selectable so &QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged never gets emitted; I'm trying to see if I can somehow fix the behavior of the constructor which seems to be the issue..

Comment: Is your GraphicsView set to interactive? if so, you can rule that out. ui->graphicsView->setInteractive(true);

Comment: it is, I realized the nodes are indeed made selectable but &QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged won't get triggered by clicking in the view unless a mousePressEvent() is triggered as well I believe